# iterate over multiple std list and move objects between them

Tags: c++

I am simulating a network where at each node I have a main list and according to the object entering this list I process this object and after that I push it into another list or I delete it.
the pseudo code of my algorithm looks like this:

```
for (iter = WBRequests.begin(); iter != WBRequests.end() ; iter++) {

    // 1- process the object
    // 2- check the second list
    for (iterSer = ServedRequests.begin(); iterSer != ServedRequests.end();iterSer++) {

        //if the *iter object satisfy some condition
        if (  (*iterser)->getIsACKok() )
            break;
    }

    if (iterSer != ServedRequests.end())
    {
        // do something and push into the list
        ServedRequests.push_back(*iter);

        iter  = WBRequests.erase(iter );
        iterSer = ServedRequests.erase(iterSer);

    }
    else { //No corresponding  object

        ServedRequests.push_back(*iter);
        iter  = WBRequests.erase(iter );
    }
}
```

I have  two questions:

1. When do I need to delete the iterators iter and iterSer.
2. At the beginning of the simulation the ServedRequests list contains only one object, so
   probably the object that I need is the end of the list. How can I get this object when I use

   ```
        if (iterSer != ServedRequests.end())
   ```

   EDIT:
   All request are pointer to object, the difference is in the attribute of the object.

   1- when new request enters the node it is pushed in the main list,
   according to the type of the object (setup, ack or release) I
   process this object and I insert it to the served list and delete it
   from the main list.

   2- For example each node send a setup packet,pushed in the main list, process it, and
   store it in the servedlist. When the packet ack arrives to the main list I need to
   check if the corresponding setup packet is here or not. The same for the
   release packet.

   3- At the beginning, the served list in each node has 1 setup packet and one ack 
   packet, when the release packet arrives I need to iterate over the whole list (later I 
   will have mode packet in the served list)

Comment: What's the version of C++ and compiler do you use and what's the type of ServedRequests?

Comment: I am using omnet4.5 with eclipse CDT 8.2.1,  g++ 4.7 in MINGW32, the two list contains pointer to object:
     list<setupobject*> WBRequests;
     list<setupobject*> ServedRequests;

Comment: Right now this: `for (iterSer = /*... */;iterSer++) if ((*iter)->getIsACKok())` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. `iter` doesn't vary between iterations, so it'll either always be false or always be true, won't it? Was the `if` intended to use `iterSer` instead of `iter`, perhaps?

Comment: according to the omnet manual c++11 is not supported yet in the version that I am using.

Comment: @jerry: yes you alright. I edit it.

Comment: When do you want to delete the iterators iter and iterSer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assume your code IS NOT multithreaded (else it won't work).
2. You delete iterator when you want it to become invalid and to definitively remove its element from the list, usually ather pushing it in another list you delete it.
3. I don't understand what you need. If you have 1 object just use `list.begin()` to get it. If you need the last object of the list you can do `--list.end()`, but only if you have a doubly linked list ( "operator --" will not work for "forward_list")

Bonus point:

You are doing `iter++` and `iterServ++` but that's unecessary since you already take iterator to next element

```
iter  = WBRequests.erase(iter ); //erase Element1 and returns Element2
//if you do iter++...
iter++;               //... now iter is pointing to Element3 (you skipped Element2!)
```

Without further details I can't help:

- Does a request born in a node and die in 2nd node connected to the 1st one?
- Does something "external" creates requests? (since that's a network it could also be that when processing a node it generates further requests.
- Does it need to be multithreaded?
- Does each node just have Requests and Served lists without communicating with other nodes?

Keep in count that a network is a graph, so you have many nodes and each node is connected to many other nodes.

EDIT:

probably the unwanted behaviour is caused by "erase". Since when you call erase you already advance the iterator by 1, there's no need to do it again.

```
for (iter = WBRequests.begin(); iter != WBRequests.end() ; ) //no increment here
for (iterSer = ServedRequests.begin(); iterSer != ServedRequests.end(); )  // no increment here

    //...

    //when you erase both no need to increment
    iter  = WBRequests.erase(iter );
    iterSer = ServedRequests.erase(iterSer);

    //...

    //do not increment iterSer since its already ended
    iter  = WBRequests.erase(iter );
```

Comment: I cannot use list.begin() because later I will have more object that I need to iterate over them. Please have a look to the edit that I added.

Comment: ah ok now it clear to me. The error is incrementing twice the iterator see my edit (at least, that's strange for me a double increment, it is not necessarily your problem if it is not, we need further details)

Comment: Thanks it is more clear now for me!
That means if the object in the main list will be deleted or pushed in another list no need to increment?
and how if I just process the object by changing the value of its attribute? should I add iter ++ ?

Comment: "erase" is the only operation that returns "the next element" (apart of course "++"). If you just push without erasing, the iterator is not advanced.

Comment: It works thanks! I still have some strange behavior when I push_back *iter into the second list. Do I need to erase and delete  *iter also or just push back and use iter++

Comment: Yup of course my fault, I showed you there's no need to increment when erasing, but moving elements between containers is a different thing. You need to use `splice` to move elements. So instead of doing "push" and other things you just need to get iterator to element you want to move `iter` from your "sourceList" after that, you will move it to "desiredList" with the following function:
`desiredList.splice(desiredList.end(),sourceList,iter);`

Comment: Now the problem is that the iterator in the main list seems to be invalidated and I can't do anything after using splice and trying to increment iter ++ to go the next element in the main list

Comment: `iteratorType iter2(iter);//copy construct new iterator to advance` 
`iter2++; `
`splice(...,iter,...) //remove old iterator from list`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. When do I need to delete the iterators iter and iterSer.

Delete when you don't want to use it anymore. I think the problem is: `std::list::erase` returns the iterator following the last removed element, it just a return value, not a mandatory input parameter. So do you really need assign the returned value to iter or iterServ?
Whenever there is `erase` operation in loop, take care of your change condition in `for` since it may skip 1 element when `erase` succeed.

> 2. if (iterSer != ServedRequests.end())

I don't think it's a problem. ServedRequests.end() returns an iterator to the element **following the last element** of the container.http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end At the beginning, ServedRequests  has 1 object, the lines in for loop will be executed 1 time.

Comment: Yes I think the problem comes from erasing the iterator!